# How to access nested values of a JSON file when they are nested multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON file like the example listed below.

```json
"SOLAR_SYSTEM": {
      "PLANETS": {
        "PLANET": [
          {
            "NAME": "Mercury",
            "DISTANCE": "57.91km",
            "RADIUS": "2340km",
            "LENGTH_OF_YEAR": "0.24085",
            "DAY": "88",
            "MASS": "0.054",
            "DENSITY": "6.03"
          },
          {
            "NAME": "Earth",
            "DISTANCE": "149.60",
            "RADIUS": "6371",
            "LENGTH_OF_YEAR": "1.000039",
            "DAY": "24",
            "MASS": "1.00",
            "DENSITY": "5.517",
            "SATELLITES": {
              "SATELLITE": {
                "NAME": "Moon",
                "DISTANCE_FROM_PLANET": "384405",
                "ORBIT": "27.322"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "NAME": "Mars",
            "DISTANCE": "227.9",
            "RADIUS": "3324",
            "LENGTH_OF_YEAR": "1.88089",
            "DAY": "24.5",
            "MASS": "0.107",
            "DENSITY": "4.16",
            "SATELLITES": {
              "SATELLITE": [
                {
                  "NAME": "Phobos",
                  "DISTANCE_FROM_PLANET": "9380",
                  "ORBIT": "0.319"
                },
                {
                  "NAME": "Deimos",
                  "DISTANCE_FROM_PLANET": "23500",
                  "ORBIT": "1.262"
                }
```

My question is how to access the data, specifically the SATELLITES --> SATELLITE --> name, distance_from_planet, and orbit.

The code that I've written below works for accessing the data of the non-nested data (a planet's name, distance, radius, etc).  As seen below, I have tried using conditional statements to check if a planet has a satellite, but with no success.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.getJSON("./json/planets.json", function(data){

      //Loop to retrieve and put data in for non nested json
      for(i = 0; i < data.SOLAR_SYSTEM.PLANETS.PLANET.length; i++){

        index = i + 1;

        //All fields that aren't nested
        $("#pName" + index).html(data.SOLAR_SYSTEM.PLANETS.PLANET[i].NAME);
        $("#pDistance" + index).html(data.SOLAR_SYSTEM.PLANETS.PLANET[i].DISTANCE);
        $("#pRadius" + index).html(data.SOLAR_SYSTEM.PLANETS.PLANET[i].RADIUS);
        $("#pLength" + index).html(data.SOLAR_SYSTEM.PLANETS.PLANET[i].LENGTH_OF_YEAR);
        $("#pDay" + index).html(data.SOLAR_SYSTEM.PLANETS.PLANET[i].DAY);
        $("#pMass" + index).html(data.SOLAR_SYSTEM.PLANETS.PLANET[i].MASS);
        $("#pDensity" + index).html(data.SOLAR_SYSTEM.PLANETS.PLANET[i].DENSITY);

        if(data.SOLAR_SYSTEM.PLANETS.PLANET[i].SATELLITES == null){

            continue;

          }else{

            $("#pSatName_" + index).html(data.SOLAR_SYSTEM.PLANETS.PLANET[i].SATELLITES.SATELLITE.NAME);
            $("#pDistanceFP_" + index).html(data.SOLAR_SYSTEM.PLANETS.PLANET[i].SATELLITES.SATELLITE.DISTANCE_FROM_PLANET);
            $("#pOrbit_" + index).html(data.SOLAR_SYSTEM.PLANETS.PLANET[i].SATELLITES.SATELLITE.ORBIT);

            //console.log(data.SOLAR_SYSTEM.PLANETS.PLANET[i].SATELLITES.SATELLITE.NAME);

          }
        }
```

Comment: Do you have control over the JSON format? I ask as there is inconsistency in the type of the value for satellites.satellite; sometimes it's an object, sometimes it's an array. It really should always be an array, even if there's only 1 entry.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan I don't have control over the JSON format.  It was given to me like that by my professor and they said they didn't want it changed.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you can cut down a lot of typing with object destructuring.

```
let {PLANET} = data.SOLAR_SYSTEM.PLANETS
for(i = 0; i < PLANET.length; i++){
    if(PLANET[i].SATTELITES)
        let {SATTELITE} = PLANET[i].SATTELITES
    else let SATTELITE = null
```

Then you don't have to type out the whole thing every time.

Like Rory said, data consistency would go a long way, but if you have no control over that you can check whether SATTELITE is an array or an object and access it appropriately.

```
if(SATTELITE && SATTELITE instanceof Array){
    access = SATTELITE[num][key]
} 
else if(SATTELITE && SATTELITE instanceof Object{
    access = SATTELITE[key]
}
```